# Is it possible to have a input and a span on the same line in flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm struggling and i don't know if it is possible to have  in a flutter app something like this:

[image]

Where the 'dasdeae' is an input text field and the '@ippportalegre.pt' is just a span with a fixed text

right now i have this as a display:

[image]

In the Number of Student/Teacher input filed i want to do it, like in the first image...is that possible in flutter??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the solution, it required adding only `suffixText: new TextSpan(text: '@ipportalegre.pt')` inside the `InputDerocoration`.

The final code is as follows:

```
new TextFormField(
    maxLines: 1,
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
      labelText: "Number of Student/Teacher",
      suffixText: new TextSpan(text: '@ipportalegre.pt).text,
      hintText: "Your student number ",
    ),
    controller: _userController,
    inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(_regUser)],
    validator: validations.userValidation,
  )
```

and the final image (without the grey tones):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. You can wrap all the widgets in a Row widget:

```
new Row(children: <Widget> [ TextField1, Textfield2 ])
```

See more [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html)